# jQuery hide showing odd behaviour

Tags: jquery

I'm having a jQuery problem which I haven't seen before. My script hides certain wrappers, and this works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE. The odd thing is when I open the IE console and refresh the page to see the log, then it works as I expect it too. It ONLY fixes when refreshing with developer tools open though!

Here is a console snippet:

```
$.get('/help-and-advice/purchase-wizard/product-details/' + product_id, function(data) {

          console.log(data);

          $.each(data.show, function() {
            $.each(this, function(index) {
              $('#' + data.show[index]).show();
            });
          });

          $.each(data.hide, function() {
            $.each(this, function(index) {
              $('#' + data.hide[index]).hide();
            });
          });
```

In the console log the wrapper I want hidden is listed within the data.show object too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE fails when a console statement is present and the console is not open

Change it to

```
window.console && console.log(...)
```

or comment it out or remember to hit F12 before testing

---

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mQPgz/):

Simple version:

```
if (!window.console) window.console={ log:function(str) { alert(str) } }
```

---

More complex version which handles comma delimited arguments - it does not unpack the objects but can handle one layer of complexity

```
if (!window.console) 
  window.console={ log:function() { 
    var text = [];
    for (var a,i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
      a=arguments[i];
      text.push(typeof a+": "+(typeof a == "object" ? a.toString():a));
    }
    alert(text.join('\n'))
  }
}

console.log("test",new Date())
```

Comment: Alternatively, remove `console.log()` completely.

Comment: Cheers mate. Good old incredibly reliable, flawless IE :D